# Lazy loading models

Tags: java, data-access-layer

Suppose I have an model object `Event` that contains a `Venue`. When I query the database to populate the venue, I want to only store the `venueid` which can be used to lazy load the `Venue`.

I have data access class `Events` (plural) with function a function like `Event findEventByName(String name)`. Similar for other model objects. If in my `Event` class, I have `getVenue` like:

```
public Venue getVenue() {
    if (this.venue == null) 
        this.venue = Venues.findVenueById(this.venueid); 
    return this.venue;
}
```

This will work, but it will couple my model with my data access. I think my design is not really "correct"? So how do I change it. For this academic project I think I won't be using a 3rd party library like Hibernate to get a feel of how this might be implemented.

Comment: It's not actually that bad; I guess the question is how many different data access ways do you have ? If you have many then you probably want to do it via interface, otherwise it looks ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're correct in that its not the best design to couple your object model to you data access.

Modern object to relational mappers are pretty advanced. EclipseLink, for example, can dynamically modify the bytecode of the classfiles to provide for features like lazy loading. They call it [weaving](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_Application_Development_%28ELUG%29#Using_Weaving).

Comment: Oh, then perhaps, I can leave it as it is, or when I populate my model, I inject the DataAccess object too.